# Deal with dependencies error messages when dropping tables

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, drop-table

I need to drop tables that are not used somewhere else in my database (mainly views). I have listed a series of `DROP TABLE...` commands but I can't run them at once because an error message is issued each time a used table is found. I would need a command that ignore such messages (and then do not remove the used tables) and jump to the next command.

For instance:

```
DROP TABLE schema1.table1 ;
DROP TABLE schema1.table2 ;
DROP TABLE schema1.table3 ;
DROP TABLE schema1.table4 ;
DROP TABLE schema1.table5 ;
```

In this example, say `table1` and `table3` are used in views whereas tables 2, 4 and 5 are not. If I run the script, I have an error message for `table1`. I have then to comment the line and run the script again. Then, `table2` is dropped properly and I get an error message again for `table3`. I then have to comment this line and run the script again. I eventually get the 2 last tables dropped.

The point is that I have hundreds of such tables, used and not used mixed together...

Comment: I guess you need this`DROP TABLE  schema1.table1 CASCADE`, `CASECADE`- _Automatically drop objects that depend on the table (such as views)_.. What's your error message??

Comment: I couldn't find any "continue on error" option for pgAdmin. However, I think this is the default behaviour for the psql client, which you can launch from pgAdmin's "Plugins" menu. From psql, you can run your script with `\i '/path/to/script.sql'`.

Comment: Maybe use pgscript (I wrote plsql but i think its for oracle), create a method/function that execute all these method in a loop with exception error handling each call (so when an exception is thrown, you can carry on). Can't give you more detail as I'm not good at it.

Comment: @Nick Barnes: I get the same error through psql client...

Comment: @Nick Barnes: ...but it worked fine without `\i`option! Thanks a lot for putting me on psql client way.

Answer (score 0):

It's plpgsql actualy (I wrote plsql in comments).

There is an example on http://www.jaredlog.com/?p=137

Just replace "EXCEPTION WHEN UNDEFINED_TABLE THEN" in the function with the exception's name thrown when you try to execute it and it should work.

I think you can even remove the "WHEN UNDEFINED_TABLE" so it catches all exceptions.

Use this function with your table names as parameter (not the whole query).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nick Barnes comment, I found a simplier way to do so:

1. Create a SQL file with this content:

   ```
   \set ON_ERROR_STOP 0

   DROP TABLE schema1.table1;
   DROP TABLE schema1.table2;    
   DROP TABLE schema1.table3;
   DROP TABLE schema1.table4;
   DROP TABLE schema1.table5;
   ```
2. Call this file through psql client:

   ```
   'D:/myFile.sql'
   ```

This drops `table1` and `table3`!